# Build Service Error: xcodebuild was terminated because it produced no activity for 600 seconds

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-bots

While tests run and pass most of the time, once or twice per day we get failed builds on our Xcode Bot Servers with result `internal-build-error`:

> Bot Issue for  (error) [...] Build Service Error: xcodebuild
>   was terminated because it produced no activity for 600 seconds (use
>   sudo xcscontrol --configure-integration-timeout to increase this
>   timeout)

I haven't tried increasing the timeout, since 10 minutes seems like a lot for not receiving any output.

I'm looking for other ideas on how to prevent this issue from happening.